# IE11 reason for css attribute "height: inherit"?

Tags: inheritance

I have a table with 2 fieldsets and each with 1 div. With css style Attribute height: inherit the height will be the same in FF. In IE11 it doesnt work.

what i found until now is:

- inherit doesnt work in ie compatibilty mode so i turn it off
- inherit works only in ie if "`<!DOCTYPE html>`" is included but it is

Also i cannot use jquery for automatic height calculation because there is no height given ... or i'am wrong?

See the example which works on FF but not on IE11

http://jsfiddle.net/fwLxj3rr/3/

someone there who can fixed it for IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it ... with jquery

gave both fieldsets an ID and use this

```
var highestCol = Math.max($('#Environment').outerHeight(),$('#Additional').outerHeight());
        $('#Environment').height(highestCol),$('#Additional').height(highestCol);
```